# Determine what pages are in my header

Tags: custom-header

I'm using the Howe's family of themes for my WordPress site. Two pages ("about" and "sample" at least one of which came with the installation) appear in my header. I'd like to add more, but I wouldn't like every page I add be in my header.

Unfortunately I don't see any menu that says "These are the six pages I want to show up in my header" or any checkbox in the individual page that says "Make this page show in the header" - how do I determine what pages show and what one's do not?

Meta: unsure about the tag I put on there, there doesn't seem to be one that applies, and [headers](/questions/tagged/headers) was about HTTP headers which I don't need... Feel free to clean that up and retag appropriately (and remove this notice.)

Comment: Do the Howe themes not use the standard WordPress menus? You need to contact Howe themes support, this stack is not a support avenue for premium themes ( https://themeforest.net/item/howes-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/9616552 )

Comment: I  don't really know, Tom. I would assume the major themes all use the same WordPress menus, since it would reduce development time and it would provide integrations with addons. I toss it in there in case someone happens to know some domain specific knowledge. A theme-agnostic answer, if I had to guess, would point me in the right direction.

Comment: Appearance > Menus.

Comment: @JacobPeattie There's nothing in there. It wants me to enter the name of my first menu. I created a test menu and added a few pages but it didn't show, so I suspect this is not the list showing in the header.

Comment: Did you choose a display location for the new menu?

Comment: @Whee I did not. It just started showing by default.

Comment: I mean for the test menu you created, did you choose a display location? as you said it didnt show. Location such as 'Primary Menu'. If you can get that test menu to display then you can disable the one showing by default using css. Some themes show the first so many pages by default in a menu even if you havent created one.